# php_network_getaddress error when trying to install CAS via PEAR

Tags: php, pear

I'm following instructions to install PHP CAS [as described on their website](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/casc/phpcas+installation+guide)

> With PEAR
>       latest stable release (current 1.3.4):
>           to install new
>
> ```
>         pear install  https://developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/current.tgz
> ```

But I get this error

```
$> sudo pear install  https://developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/current.tgz
downloading current.tgz ...
Starting to download current.tgz (96,108 bytes)
.....................done: 96,108 bytes
Connection to `__uri:443' failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

I did some googling and didn't find anything about `php_network_getaddresses` in regards to PEAR.

My curl or wget library (whichever PEAR uses) seems fine:

```
$> wget  https://developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/current.tgz
--2017-01-31 21:13:12--  https://developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/current.tgz
Resolving developer.jasig.org (developer.jasig.org)... 199.119.127.181
Connecting to developer.jasig.org (developer.jasig.org)|199.119.127.181|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 96108 (94K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘current.tgz’

100%[=====================================================================================================================================================================>] 96,108       537KB/s   in 0.2s

2017-01-31 21:13:13 (537 KB/s) - ‘current.tgz’ saved [96108/96108]

$> curl -O  https://developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/current.tgz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 96108  100 96108    0     0   104k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  104k
```

How can I troubleshoot this error?

```
$> pear -V
PEAR Version: 1.10.1
PHP Version: 5.6.29
Zend Engine Version: 2.6.0
Running on: Linux hostname 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 22:10:57 UTC 2015 x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried installing this package with my setup as well and got the same error. Something might be wrong with the package itself.
Try to download file and install it from local source.

```
[dimitri@tinynetbook ~]$ pear install  https://developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/current.tgz
downloading current.tgz ...
Starting to download current.tgz (96,108 bytes)
.....................done: 96,108 bytes
Connection to `__uri:443' failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
[dimitri@tinynetbook ~]$ pear install  http://developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/current.tgz
downloading current.tgz ...
Starting to download current.tgz (96,108 bytes)
.....................done: 96,108 bytes
Connection to `__uri:443' failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
[dimitri@tinynetbook ~]$ pear install  developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/current.tgz
Attempting to discover channel "developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php"...
Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel "developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php"...
unknown channel "developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php" in "developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/current.tgz"
invalid package name/package file "developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/current.tgz"
install failed
[dimitri@tinynetbook ~]$ wget  developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/current.tgz
--2017-01-31 16:27:15--  http://developer.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/current.tgz
Resolving developer.jasig.org (developer.jasig.org)... 199.119.127.181
Connecting to developer.jasig.org (developer.jasig.org)|199.119.127.181|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 96108 (94K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘current.tgz’

current.tgz                         100%[================================================================>]  93.86K   325KB/s    in 0.3s    

2017-01-31 16:27:15 (325 KB/s) - ‘current.tgz’ saved [96108/96108]

[dimitri@tinynetbook ~]$ sudo pear install current.tgz 
install ok: channel://__uri/CAS-1.3.4
[dimitri@tinynetbook ~]$
```